# CSS alignment issue with input box and font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is as below:

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="leftFormComp">
                                <!--  Password Box -->
                                <div class="selectWrapper">
                                    <!-- add class "error" to show validation message -->
                                    <label for="ext-comp-1037" class="inputLabel"><fmt:message key="registration.password"/>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1037" class="x-form-element">
                                        <input type="password" class="required" name="password" id="ext-comp-1037" />
                                        <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="leftFormComp">
                                <!-- Password Box -->
                                <div class="selectWrapper">
                                    <!-- add class "error" to show validation message -->
                                    <label for="ext-comp-1038" class="inputLabel"><fmt:message key="registration.retypepassword"/>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1038" class="x-form-element">
                                        <input type="password" class="required" name="password2" id="ext-comp-1038" />
                                        <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword2" style="float: right;"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I have tried using float, margin property but the font-awesome eye icon does not move inside the text box.

The page from the above code appears as below:
[HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhifG.png)

This is happening in my application, but when I run the code alone in JS Fiddle using margin-left:-30px it works fine. The image in my code after setting margin-left:-30px is as below:
[Margin-left:30px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBOH2.png)

I have tried everything from my end. If someone could assist me with the same it would be great.

EDIT1: Image added after Tanner Dolby's code.

[Tanner Dolby's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGkvW.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Plz include your css.

Comment: Why are you floating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After minor modification in Tanner Dolby's solution, the below code worked perfectly fine for me.

```css
.myFlex {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: center;
}

.fa-eye {
   margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="myFlex">
   <input type="password" class="required" name="password" id="ext-comp-1037">
   <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: relative` could be the solution.
You could add something like this to you css file.

```
.fa-eye {
    position: relative;
    left: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this =)

```css
#showeye {
position:relative;
left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="leftFormComp">
  <!--  Password Box -->
  <div class="selectWrapper">
    <!-- add class "error" to show validation message -->
    <label for="ext-comp-1037" class="inputLabel"><fmt:message key="registration.password"/>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1037" class="x-form-element">
      <input type="password" class="required" name="password" id="ext-comp-1037" />
      <span id="showeye">
      <i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="leftFormComp">
  <!-- Password Box -->
  <div class="selectWrapper">
    <!-- add class "error" to show validation message -->
    <label for="ext-comp-1038" class="inputLabel"><fmt:message key="registration.retypepassword"/>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1038" class="x-form-element">
      <input type="password" class="required" name="password2" id="ext-comp-1038" />
            <span id="showeye">
<i class="fa fa-eye" id="togglePassword2"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```